# Disable all checkboxs when one checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

im like two days fighting against this, and i wish some1 can help

im using a PHP that generats 4 checkboxes

```
<form method="post" class="car_booking_form"  >
<div class="booking-item-price-calc">
<div class="row row-wrap">
    <div class="col-md-<?php echo esc_attr($col) ?> singe_cars" data-car-id="<?php the_ID()?>">
        <?php $list = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'cars_equipment_list',true); ?>
        <?php
        if(!empty($list)){
            foreach($list as $k=>$v){
                $v['cars_equipment_list_price'] = apply_filters('st_apply_tax_amount',$v['cars_equipment_list_price']);

                $price_unit = isset($v['price_unit'])? $v['price_unit']: '';

                $price_unit_html='';
                switch($price_unit)
                {
                    case "per_hour":
                        $price_unit_html=__('/hour',ST_TEXTDOMAIN);
                        break;
                    case "per_day":
                        $price_unit_html=__('',ST_TEXTDOMAIN);
                        break;
                    default:
                        $price_unit_html=__('',ST_TEXTDOMAIN);
                        break;
                }
                echo '<div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input class="i-check equipment" data-price-unit="'.$price_unit.'" data-title="'.$v['title'].'" data-price="'.$v['cars_equipment_list_price'].'" type="checkbox" />'.$v['title'].'
                            <span class="pull-right">'.TravelHelper::format_money($v['cars_equipment_list_price']).''.$price_unit_html.'</span>
                        </label>
                   </div>';
            }
        }
        ?>
```

if i hade 4 normal labels i could give theme Ids and use a JS script, now the Checkboxs gets generated automatically and i dont know how to manage it so when a Checkbox is checked the other 3 gets disabled

thanks and sorry for my bad EN

Comment: That's not how checkboxes work.  If you want only one active choice, you need radio buttons.

Comment: Dave even using Radio i still having a probleme, im using Foreach in PHP wich is a loop, so once i get the 4 radios i can select theme all bcoz for every line i got an individual radio

Comment: There is a lot of code in the answers below, but I believe (untested) that if you just add a name to your input field (e.g., `<input type="radio" name="xx" class="i-check-equipment" data-price ...`) the radio buttons will act as a group even if they are generated in a Foreach loop.  Using checkboxes and adding external logic to give radio behavior to them will just confuse users - checkboxes aren't supposed to update themselves.

Comment: WaaAAaaAAAh !!!!!! it WorkeD !!!!!!! u Really ROCKS !!!! i never known that giving a name could make the php consider theme a groupe but it make sence :D a Milions of thanks man :D

Comment: now i got another problem if i switch to radios i got a bug on default price once i loaud the page the price shown as default doesnt not match with the i setup but once i hit one of the radio the price gets ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There is no problem with the use of radios or checkboxes. If you want to make a group of radios, then you need to add them the same NAME.**

Since you can change the HTML generated by your script, then you can add a name to your radio/checkbox.

If you want to make it with checkboxes, then change the part of your script that generates the html to this:

```
echo '<div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input class="i-check equipment equipment-disabling-checkbox" data-price-unit="'.$price_unit.'" data-title="'.$v['title'].'" data-price="'.$v['cars_equipment_list_price'].'" type="checkbox" />'.$v['title'].'
                        <span class="pull-right">'.TravelHelper::format_money($v['cars_equipment_list_price']).''.$price_unit_html.'</span>
                    </label>
               </div>';
```

*Here we add a class **equipment-disabling-checkbox** to know what/which checkbox disable.*

Then, supposing that you want an INDEPENDENT checkbox to disable all of them, add it out of your foreach loop.

```
// Disable all other checkboxes
echo '<div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input class="i-check equipment" type="checkbox" id="disable-equipment-checkboxes" /> Disable all
                    </label>
               </div>';
```

*Here we define a "disable all" checkbox.*

and add this to your JQuery handlers:

```
$(document).on("change", "#disable-equipment-checkboxes", function() {
    if ( $(this).prop('checked') ) {
        $(".equipment-disabling-checkbox").prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $(".equipment-disabling-checkbox").prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

*And here we handle the change event of the "disable all" checkbox and enable/disable the other checkboxes.*

If you want another solution, explain yourself better please.

**P.D.: I made a fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/s6fe9/559/**

**EDIT: To cover the needs of Omar properly:**

Change the HTML echo to this:

```
echo '<div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input class="i-check equipment equipment-unique-checkbox" data-price-unit="'.$price_unit.'" data-title="'.$v['title'].'" data-price="'.$v['cars_equipment_list_price'].'" type="checkbox" />'.$v['title'].'
                    <span class="pull-right">'.TravelHelper::format_money($v['cars_equipment_list_price']).''.$price_unit_html.'</span>
                </label>
           </div>';
```

*This will add a class name to all the unique checkboxes.*

Then, add this piece of code to your JQuery handlers:

```
$(document).on("change", ".equipment-unique-checkbox", function() {
    if ( $(this).prop('checked') ) {
        $(".equipment-unique-checkbox").prop('checked', false);
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $(".equipment-unique-checkbox").prop('checked', false);
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

*And here we uncheck all of them, and check the selected one.*

**Notice that the repeated line that unchecks all of them is needed in both parts of the if condition to work properly.**

Here you have another fiddle :)
https://jsfiddle.net/s6fe9/561/

**P.D.: I realized that the code for the HTML edit were broken somehow. So I updated it.**

Comment: Hi Asier first i would like to thank u so much for all ur effort
this is the web so u can understand well the probleme http://easytobook.ma/st_car/tangier-to-chefchaouen/ ull find 4 checkboxes i was trying to figurout how to give the costumer the option to chose only one of the radios/checkboxs so he cant generats a bug in prices,  im using wordpress and the 4 checkboxes gets generated as u saw with the loop that gets the list and echo it

Comment: So you just want to mark one of them, don't you? I mean. I f you mark 1, the others can't be marked. Okay. I got you. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Yes sir thats exactly what i want

Comment: still not working :/ can i have ur email please and ill share with u my Codeanywhere link

Comment: asier_paz@hotmail.es But you have to post here the solution to help other people, ok?

Comment: Hey. I edited your prices.php in codeanywhere and I saved it thinking that I could share it with you, but it says "Access denied" so... Maybe you gave me edit permissions and I edited your file. Check it out. If that doesn't work, you only have to change the JQuery part and put it somewhere else where you have your jQuery code or in the very bottom of the body.

Comment: Still not working it worked for u bcoz u created a list of checkboxes and u gave theme the same class name it works like that but in my case it doesnt :S i saw u gave the class equipment-unique-checkbox to the Echo so all checkbox share the same class and u wrote the Jquery at the bottom but i refreshed and still not workin :,(

Comment: But, in the HTLM, you see the class, right? So it is a problem with the JQuery code. But I am 100% sure that the code works, so, as I said, you have to check where the other JQuery code go.

Comment: Silly question. You have JQuery imported into your project, right?

Comment: Can you try replacing the $(document) for jQuery(document)? Or maybe wrapping the whole code into a jquery ready handler as follows: jQuery(document).ready( function() { //CODE HERE })

Comment: yes im using Wordpress so jQuery is imported to the whole project i even tried to import Google CDN in the same file to make sure jQuery is imported

Comment: your right in one thing, i just made a test and before adding the googls CDN Java wasnt imported i made a simple botton to check JQ and now its runing but even after importing JS still not workin

Comment: add the script to the very bottom of you body. I see in your web an undefined error but I don't know why is it there.  which jquery version are you using?

Comment: im using          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Dave gave us a solution, wich is changing the Checkboxs to Radios and by giving to the loop a name PHP consider theme a group and not individuals and it start acting like a normal radio group :D

Comment: I gave you that same answer in the very beginning of my answer. Haha. I just helped you out with checkboxes because though you wanted like that.

Comment: haha im sorry man maybe i didnt read u well, i marked ur answer as solution thank u so much for ur help and effort uv been verry helpfull :D

Comment: Was a pleasure dude. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it works:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').is('checked',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
   $( "input[type='checkbox']").attr( "disabled", true);
   $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have no access to that foreach loop at all? If you do, you can try something along these lines using radio buttons:

```
echo '<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="' . $price_unit . '" name="price" />' . $v['title'] . '
    <span class="pull-right"></span>
  </label>
</div>';
```

Keeping in mind, the above is just a stripped down version of yours so you may need to add in all your data variables.

Comment: ThePav using radios doesnt work, when using foreach loop php consider every radio as an individual radio and not a group of radios, so it shows 4 radios but u can select all of theme and not only one

Comment: @OmarAguado, if you give the radio buttons the same name `name="price"`, as long as they're within the same `<form>`, they will work how you expect them to work.